# VBA for Dynamic Vlookup and updating next available column

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, vlookup

Very new to vba but trying to optimize a process for data entry.

I would like to have the following steps:

1. New data always entered on sheet 2 (MSIMPORT)
2. vlookup on sheet 1(NEEDBYDATES) from data on sheet 2
3. copy paste data
4. new data entered on sheet 2 and copied in next available column (loop?)

I think my vlookup works and i have my range to go to the next column i KNOW is available but i cant seem to get it to update on the next 'loop'/when new data is entered (new data overrides previous).

Help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub vlookup_Update()

   'variables
    Dim NeedByDate As Worksheet, MSImport As Worksheet
    Dim NeedByLastRow As Long, datalastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim datarng As Range
    
    Set NeedByDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NeedByDates")
    Set MSImport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MSImport")
    
    'find last row/columnn from ms project import
        
       NeedByLastRow = NeedByDate.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    datalastrow = MSImport.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        Set datarng = MSImport.Range("a2:d" & datalastrow)
        
    'find next blank column on need by sheet
    Dim cell As Range
        Set cell = ActiveCell
    If cell.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
    End If
    
    
    For i = 2 To NeedByLastRow
        On Error Resume Next
        NeedByDate.Range(i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup( _
            NeedByDate.Range("a" & i).Value, datarng, 4, False)
                  
        Next i
        
        Cells.Columns.AutoFit
        
        
    Worksheets("NeedByDates").UsedRange
    Worksheets("needbydates").UsedRange.Select
    Worksheets("needbydates").UsedRange.copypaste
      
      
End Sub
```

TIA

Comment: What is `Worksheets("needbydates").UsedRange.copypaste`? There's no `Range.copypaste` method.

Comment: Can this be achieved using FILTER / XLOOKUP formula if you are using office 365.

Comment: Rather than `On Error Resume Next`, why not program for the specific instances where you fail?  This would also allow you to see if you have a separate issue than the known error.  Additionally, avoid `.Select` where possible.

Comment: `NeedByDate.Range(i).Value` seems like there's something missing here

Comment: 'Worksheets("needbydates").UsedRange.copypaste' was for pasting data assuming then the next data range would go to the next availble empty column